# Locate string in another string?

Tags: swift, macos

I have a NSTextField that contains the hardware ID of the user's Mac.

I also have a login button that should segue into another NSViewController if the NSTextField's .stringValue matches a string pulled from a URL.

Here is the code that is what I am trying to portray.

```
if let url = URL(string: "URL HERE")
            {
                do
                {
                    let contents = try String(contentsOf: url)

                    print(contents)

                    if contents.contains(serialTextField.stringValue)
                    {
                        print("exists")

                        //SEGUE
                    }
```

The contents when printed is something like (3 individual mac hardware ids made up for example);

```
1j2k9j5g8j7b
4n5k5s9db31d
p9d4v8s2z81d
```

The problem I am having is if I just enter (for example) the number "1" into the NSTextField, then when I press the login button it says it exists, which it shouldn't only a matching hardware id should be matched.

How do I match a proper hardware ID to what is in contents and not match a single number or letter or wrong hardware id.

How would I say there is a match when searching 4n5k5s9db31d in the contents.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you please post the actual string that you got from the url. e.g. you got the ids from urls are joined  by a comma, then you can break the string with delimiter then run a for loop and check whether any of the string matches with your NSTextfield's value.

Comment: That is how the actual string looks like which I got from the URL

Comment: Note that you should never use `String(contentsOf: url)` or any other code that synchronously loads content from a remote URL in a real app that users will use. That code will freeze your app until the data is fetched, and if there is a network problem your app may be terminated for being non-responsive. Even a minor network "hiccup" makes your app seem clunky and non-responsive. You should learn how to use the `URLSession` class instead.

Comment: @DuncanC, Note, the file is 39 bytes so I highly doubt there will be a minor network "hiccup". I also support the URL failing so my app crashes otherwise (coded by me). URLSessions is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following which broke up the contents into single lines.

```
if let url = URL(string: "URL HERE")
            {
                do
                {
                    let contents = try String(contentsOf: url)

                    let components = contents.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)

                    for component in components
                    {
                        print(component)

                        if component == serialTextField.stringValue
                        {
                            print("found")
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that the larger 'contents' string will check whether it contains the smaller serialTextField.stringValue, which is not what you want. You want to check whether two hardware IDs are identical to one another.

Perhaps you could try to split 'contents' into three distinct strings, so that you have an array of strings like so:

```
let contentsArray = ["1j2k9j5g8j7b","4n5k5s9db31d","p9d4v8s2z81d"]
```

And now you would be able to use contains like this:

```
if contentsArray.contains(serialTextField.stringValue) { 
    print("exists") 
    //segue
}
```

Here's an example in Xcode's documentation about using the contains() method with an array of strings:

```
let cast = ["Vivien", "Marlon", "Kim", "Karl"]
    print(cast.contains("Marlon"))
    // Prints "true"
    print(cast.contains("James"))
    // Prints "false"
```